# How can I customise all assignments to window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, html

In my JavaScript application, we have multiple places where we have used `window.location.href="any string";`. Now I want to write JS code in only one place (probably using `window.location.prototype`) to override assignments to href, so that I can append a parameter to all instances.

I want to append a parameter (e.g. `"?abc=1234"`) to all urls which are assigned to `window.location.href`.

I want to write code that means when e.g.

```
window.location.href = "abc.html";
```

is written, it should actually result in the `href` being set to `abc.html?abc=1234`.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Really interesting question. I’m not sure that JavaScript lets you customise property assignments like this. You might have to write a function like `setLocationHref()`, and replace all your assignments to `window.location.href` with calls to your function. I’d be fascinated if there’s an alternative though.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "?abc=1234"
```

I just test this in WebKit DevTools/

Comment: Actually in my application , we have multiple instances where we have used window.location.href="any string"; Now i want write JS code at only one place  (probably using window.location.prototype) to override href, so that i can append my parameter to all instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually do this.

It's more of the JavaScript engine which runs the page. All records in most browsers which are stored of your browsing is the history. Hardly anything else. So basically to the browser, there is no difference between a `meta` redirect, a `header` redirect and a `javascript` redirect.

Unless I'm wrong.